# What is the difference between bundle and bundle update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get two different results when using the two commands `bundle` and `bundle update`

If I use `bundle update`, I get the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    requirejs-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.1.1) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0.rc2) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.0.rc2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    requirejs-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.1.1) ruby

    rails (4.0.0.rc2)
```

But if I use just `bundle`, I get the following :

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (3.2.2)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0.rc2) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 4.0.0.rc2) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

The errors point to two different dependencie issues, but both commands are `fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...` and `Resolving dependencies...`, so how are they different?

I have always used just `bundle`, but tried `bundle update` and noticed the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In a nutshell: bundle install handles changes to the Gemfile and
>   bundle update upgrades gems that are already managed by Bundler.

http://viget.com/extend/bundler-best-practices

Needless to say that `bundle` and `bundle install` are the same command, `install` is the default option for `bundle`.

Answer (score 5):

`bundle` is the same as `bundle install`, which does the following:

- Check if a `Gemfile.lock` exists. If it does, install all gems with the exact versions specified there.
- If the lock doesn't exist, install gems as specified in the `Gemfile`, using the latest available / allowable versions according to the `Gemfile`. Then create the `Gemfile.lock` to record what versions have been installed.

`bundle update` on the other hand, deletes / ignores your `Gemfile.lock` and goes straight to step two.

The error you're seeing is probably because some gem wants `active_support` to be in the `3.x.x` version range, while you seem to be trying to upgrade to Rails 4.